# Vuejs : Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location:

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a problem with the redundant of routes on `vuejs`.
I have a `Vuejs` page with Query that I would like to be able to change continuously but when I make the change `(this.$router.replace({query: newQuery}))`, It show me this Error :

```
**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location:**
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiLQI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to replace the current route with the same route you're actually in.

You should avoid the renavigation to the current location, but if you decide to not avoid it then you need to catch the promise so the browser things the exception is being handled:

Any router action is a promise, you just need to catch it:

```js
this.$router.replace({query: newQuery}).catch(()=>{});
```

[Vue Router documentation on navigation failures](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#navigation-failures)